# Android 14 EditText required double click to enter text if hard keyboard is attached

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad, android-14, android-hardware-keyboard

Till Android 13, application is working as expected, after Tablet upgraded to Android 14
EditText required double touch/click  to enter text if hard keyboard is attached.

My EdiText control looks like below.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_firstname"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
    android:background="@{viewModel.iServiceInfoDecisionMakerClick ?@drawable/bg_corners_full_round_duck_egg_blue_stroke_white_nopadding:@drawable/bg_corners_full_round_disabled_text_stroke_grey}"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:enabled="@{viewModel.iServiceInfoDecisionMakerClick ? true :false }"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_lts_td_roman_regular"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:maxLength="@integer/material_max_40"
    android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> viewModel.onServiceInfoFirstNameTextChange(text)}"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
    android:text="@{serviceContact.firstName}"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_firstname"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.31" />
```